# Trying to remove a node and save it again c#

Tags: c#

I have a program, and i want to remove a node from the tree. Ok, i can remove, but when i want to save it again it shows me a error.

```
public void InsertNode(string value)
    {
        root = InsertNode(value, root);
    }

    private Node InsertNode(string value, Node node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new Node(value, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (node.value.CompareTo(value) > 0) ---- The error is in this line
            {
                node.lChild = InsertNode(value, node.lChild);
            }
            else
            {
                node.rChild = InsertNode(value, node.rChild);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What error? Which line of code gives error? What is the use case?

Comment: Does any of the nodes have the value as "null"?

Comment: @Naruto when i remove the node i have this: curr.value = null;

Comment: Thats why it is returning error. please remove the node entirely or add one more condition to exclude null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)